# How to get rid of NetDataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am working with legacy code that serializes/deserializes objects to/from XML. 
I have few XMLs serialized by NetDataContractSerializer, and they should be deserialized.

But NetDataContractSerializer is NOT supported by .net core. So I need to get rid of it, but XMLs that was created with it should be deserialized.

Is it possible to replace NetDataContractSerializer with DataContractSerializer in this case? And if it is possible, how can I do it?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53002135/1997232).