# How to add property to DTO in a backward compatible way?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, datacontractserializer

WCF is used to transfer data between clients and a server. Old DTO:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    private string firstProperty;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FirstProperty
    {
        get => firstProperty;
        set => firstProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Clients will keep sending the old version.
The class needs to be extended to look like this:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    private string firstProperty;
    private string secondProperty;
    
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FirstProperty
    {
        get => firstProperty;
        set => firstProperty = value;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string SecondProperty
    {
        get => secondProperty;
        set => secondProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Serialization:

```cs
public static void SerializeDataContract<T>(T obj, string path)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(path, settings))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
    }
}

public static T DeserializeDataContract<T>(string path)
{
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (var s = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        return (T) serializer.ReadObject(s);
    }
}
```

The server and some clients will use the new version. If I serialize the old version and deserialize it into the new version, the following error is thrown:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Error in line 1 position 129. 'EndElement' 'TestClass' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DTOs' is not expected. Expecting element 'secondProperty'.'

The exception is usually thrown in the WCF layer but I extracted a minimal reproducible example.
If I use the XmlSerializer the error is gone. But changing the serializer is not an option because the old clients will keep using the DataContractSerializer.

So I'm having a hard time getting this to work because of the XmlSerializer attributes in combination with the DataContractSerializer. Any advice?

Comment: Try the OptionalFieldAttribute Class, which Specifies that a field can be missing from a serialization stream so that the BinaryFormatter and the SoapFormatter does not throw an exception.

Comment: Probably too late to tell you this, but the "data binding" approach you are using in your application is great for simple stable XML schemas, but becomes a nightmare when schemas start changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate that `secondProperty` is optional by marking it with [`[OptionalFieldAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.optionalfieldattribute?view=net-5.0):

```
[Serializable]
public class TestClass
{
    private string firstProperty;

    [OptionalField]
    private string secondProperty;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FirstProperty
    {
        get => firstProperty;
        set => firstProperty = value;
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string SecondProperty
    {
        get => secondProperty;
        set => secondProperty = value;
    }
}
```

When a type is marked with [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=net-5.0) but not [data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts), the data contract serializer will serialize the public and private **fields** of instances of the type -- not the properties -- in a manner similar to `BinaryFormatter`.  As such all fields are required to be present unless marked with `[OptionalField]`.

For more see *[Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/types-supported-by-the-data-contract-serializer)* and *[Version tolerant serialization: Tolerance of missing data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/version-tolerant-serialization#tolerance-of-missing-data)*.

Notes:

- To mark the backing field of an auto-implemented property as optional, see *[NetDataContractSerializer Deserialization With New Property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33813551/3744182)*.

  That being said, I don't recommend using auto-properties with `[Serializable]` types since the serialization stream will contain the names of the secret backing fields.  See *[.NET WebAPI Serialization k_BackingField Nastiness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12334382/3744182)* for details.
- You have marked your type with [`[XmlAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute), but this attribute is ignored by `DataContractSerializer`.  It only affects serialization by [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-xml-serialization).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fian5c).