# How to add property to a custom attribute in a "binary" backward compatible way

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, backwards-compatibility

Originally I have the following attribute

```
class CustomAttributeAttribute : Attribute { }
```

With usage like

```
[CustomAttribute]
public void Method() { ... }
```

Then I need to add a boolean property to the attribute:

```
class CustomAttributeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyProperty { get; set; } = false;
}
```

So for the further usage, the previous places where it was used, the `MyProperty` would be assumed `false`, and only seen as `true` when it's explicitly specified.

My question is: how do I ensure that the assemblies which already have used `MyCustomAttribute` would correctly work (that is, assume `MyProperty == false`, and also avoid other issues, whatever they are)  **without recompilation**?

As far as I understand, the attributes content is stored serialized. So maybe I should do as described in ["How to add property to DTO in a backward compatible way?" question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672610/2303202) but I have not found any explicit guidance regarding custom attributes.

Would using `OptionalFieldAttribute` be enough for me? Or, could it be so that it's not necessary and the simplest way would also work?

Smoke testing did not reveal any issues, also in the il dump adding the OptionalFieldAttribute did not seem to change the content of the attribute as it's stored in the using assembly. But I would still need some second opinion.